# Load balancing mix of GCE and non-GCE nodes

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am planning a deployment to Google Compute Engine 
and I have a customer requirement which forces me to 
have some servers out of the Google Cloud.

Is it possible to load balance traffic to these instances
along with GCE instances?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is : no you can't add external instances to a Google Cloud Load Balancer.

You could think of creating an instance proxying traffic to your external server but that is not a good, fast and reliable solution, and I think your customer is considering load balancing to have a reliable and fast configuration.

Regards.
Paolo